# Real time audio streaming library

Tags: c#, audio, streaming

I am looking to stream mic input from my android phone to a c# server. I am able to capture, and send the data fine to the c# server. My problem lies in playing that stream in real time on the server.

I cannot save to a file and read from it(as far as I know) because part of the header information for a wav file is the size of it. So that won't work since it's constantly changing.

I have all available information to play the file(sample rates, channel count, audio format(pcm 16bit)).

Does anyone know of a library that can support this? Also, I am looking for a control that can be used in a winform to control the playback of this mic data if anyone knows of one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `waveOutOpen` API (using PInvoke) to play "raw" sample data from streamed input.  This family of API calls lets you open a playback device and then queue up sample buffers (of arbitrary length each) for playback.

You do not need to save the received audio chunks to disk before playing them - in fact, you don't *want* to do this unless you actually want a recording of the audio as well.

`waveOutOpen` links:

http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidA53BE0F5147E80A51FAC4A7CA140B80436D056EC.aspx?s=waveoutopen

http://winmm.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks. This looks like what I need. I do need to save the audio too.

Comment: It's pretty easy to save raw audio to a WAV file while also playing it. Basically, you write the 44-byte header first, then start appending your chunks of raw audio. When your WAV file gets to a certain size, you go back and re-write the header to include the size values, then close the file and start a new one.